# How to determine the worst case run time of each program using big-O notation?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble understanding this question and how to get to the answer. How do you **calculate** the worst case run time?

The input of the following programs is an array A containing n integers A[ 1 ] · · · A[n]. Bound the worst case run time of each program using big-O notation.

Problem 1:

```
i = 1, total = 0 
while i < n/2:
    total = total + A[i] 
    i=i*2
```

Problem 2:

```
total = 0
S = the set {1,2,3,4...n} 
for each subset T of S
    for each element x in T
          total = total + A[x]
```

Problem 3:

```
int i = 1, j = 1; 
    for i = 1 to n:
          while (j < n && A[i] < A[j])
             j++
```

The prefix sum of an array of numbers A[ 1 ], . . . , A[n] is a second array B[ 1 ], . . . , B[n] where

B[i] = *summation from j=1 to i* A[j]

The following problems calculate the prefix sum:

Problem 4:

```
for i = 1 to n: 
    B[i] = 0;
    for j = 1 to i:
          B[i] += A[j]
```

Problem 5:

```
B[1] = A[1]; 
for i = 2 to n:
      B[i] = B[i-1] + A[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:
The algorithm performs a constant time operation (addition) at the point of each access, and that access is made while `i<n/2`. Since `i` doubles each time, the condition will no longer hold after `log(n/4)` steps , so the worst case time complexity is **O(log(n)) (logarithmic)**.

Problem 2:
The algorithm accesses each element of the array (`x` in pseudocode) as many times as it is in a subset of `S`, and performs a constant time operation at the point of access. Every element is in *2^(n-1)* subsets that that contain itself, and there are *n* such elements, so the worst case time complexity is **O(n * 2^(n)) (exponential)**.

Problem 3:
Observe that at every time the condition in the while loop is checked, the value of `i+j` increases by `1`, and the value of `i+j` can never decrease. Since `i+j` starts at `2` and can never go past `2n+1`, the overall complexity of the algorithm is **O(n) (linear)**.

Problem 4:
For a given value of `i`, the inner loop runs `i` times. Further, `i` ranges from 1 to n, so we perform 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2 constant-time computations (additions), so the overall complexity of the algorithm is **O(n^2) (quadratic)**.

Problem 5:
The algorithm accesses *n-1* elements of the array, and performs a constant time operation at the point of each access (addition), so the worst case time complexity is **O(n) (linear)**.

Comment: for problem 1, _i_ is doubled at each iteration - thus the complexity is O(log(n))

Comment: Ah, I missed that line, edited my answer!